# What are the pros and cons of having a singleton controller in test automation project

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, testng

I'm creating a Test automation project and want it to be used by TESTNG.I'm planning to have a MVC architecture in the automation project and was thinking of creating the controller singleton. Hence wanted to know the pros and cons of that as it will be accessed/ used by TESTNG which supports Multithreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on test ng specifically but I can recommend this interesting document about [writing testable code](http://misko.hevery.com/attachments/Guide-Writing%20Testable%20Code.pdf). In particular it has a section about singletons. Here are a few extracts:

> - Every test using global state needs it to start in an expected state, or the test will fail. But another object might have mutated that global state in a previous test.
> - Global state often prevents tests from being able to run in parallel, which forces test suites to run slower.
> - Singletons enforcing their own “Singletonness” end up cheating: you’ll often see mutator methods such as reset() or setForTest() on so-called singletons, because you’ll need to change the instance during tests. If you forget to reset the Singleton after a test, a later use will use the stale underlying instance and may fail in a way that’s difficult to debug.

Bottom line: avoid using a singleton if you can and use dependency injection instead. In other words, instead of:

```
public void someMethod() {
   Controller c = Controller.getInstance();
   c.doSomething();
}
```

favour:

```
public void someMethod(Controller c) {
   c.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: The Shared PDF is a true Guide !!

Answer (score 1):

In test automation, or generally you should avoid singletons.
Especially in java you normaly cannot reset a singleton for a new test case.
That leads into the siatuation that the new tets cases uses the singelton which has results from the previous one. This is bad!
One might create special singeltons, that have a resetSingleton() or a setInstance() method, which will only be used  in test cases.
 Further you coul dreset the singelton via reflection. I have done all 3 technics, but:

Best is to avoid singeltons at all.